# Travelling within Schengen area with a processing Italian residency permit

Tags: air-travel, schengen, europe, italy, permits

I know this question has been asked thousands of times on this website, however bear with me. I'm a non-EU student studying in Italy and I've had 2 residency permits issued for the entire time I've been here (1 year & half) and each time it has been valid for 1 week (first time issued) and the second time it was valid for only a couple of months. I really want to travel to Belgium, however my RP expired in February, bear in mind that I applied for renewal before it even expired in January. I was given an appointment in July, however I will not be here during the summer as my semester would be over and I will come back in September.

The real question here is: **can I, *for the love of God*, travel to Belgium for a few days and come back to Italy using only my passport, postal receipt and university enrolment papers???** I have gotten mixed answers every time! Some say I can (including the Italian director at my university) and others say I cannot. I do know quite a few people who have been able to travel within the Schengen area with an expired RP and their paperwork showing that it is being renewed.

**THANK YOU** if you read this entire thing - I know it's a lot but I am in need of a REAL answer.